# How to assign a JSON variable with row_to_json in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to create an annonymous function in PostgreSQL to create mock data for an application.. I would like to do a SELECT query first (to get data from a random charter) and convert all the rows into a JSON with row_to_json, then assign the result into a variable of type JSON.

I need this charter information so I can add it into bookings table.

This is not working, I think I don't know how to associate the result of the select with the variable previously created; I'm getting the error that charterData is null and I would like to know how I can achieve this..

This is the annonymous func in SQL:

```
BEGIN;
    DO $$
    DECLARE charterData JSON;
    DECLARE bookingId INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT row_to_json(t) INTO charterData FROM (select charter_id, name from charters) t WHERE charter_id = 1;
        INSERT INTO bookings (charter, yacht, email, date, guests, total, start_hour, end_hour, hotel, arrival_date) values (charterData, '{"test":1}', 'a', '12/10/1995', 8, '78', '123', '123', '123', '123')
        RETURNING booking_id INTO bookingId;
    END $$;
COMMIT;
```

Table charter:

```
                                        Table "public.charters"
   Column    |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |                   Default                    
-------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------
 charter_id  | integer           |           | not null | nextval('charters_charter_id_seq'::regclass)
 name        | character varying |           | not null | 
 description | character varying |           | not null | 
 sail_hours  | integer           |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "charters_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (charter_id)
    "name_charter" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "bookings" CONSTRAINT "charters_bookings_fk" FOREIGN KEY (charter) REFERENCES charters(name) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "pricing" CONSTRAINT "charters_pricing_fk" FOREIGN KEY (charter_id) REFERENCES charters(charter_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Bookings table:

```
                                         Table "public.bookings"
     Column     |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |                   Default                    
----------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------
 booking_id     | integer           |           | not null | nextval('bookings_booking_id_seq'::regclass)
 charter        | json              |           | not null | 
 yacht          | json              |           | not null | 
 email          | character varying |           | not null | 
 date           | date              |           | not null | 
 guests         | integer           |           | not null | 
 total          | numeric           |           | not null | 
 start_hour     | character varying |           | not null | 
 end_hour       | character varying |           | not null | 
 alcohol        | character varying |           |          | 
 transportation | character varying |           |          | 
 others         | character varying |           |          | 
 arrival_date   | character varying |           |          | 
 hotel          | character varying |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "bookings_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (booking_id)
    "end_hour" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (end_hour)
    "start_hour" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (start_hour)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "charters_bookings_fk" FOREIGN KEY (charter) REFERENCES charters(name) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "yachts_bookings_fk" FOREIGN KEY (yacht) REFERENCES yachts(name) ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "bookings_extra" CONSTRAINT "bookings_extra_fk" FOREIGN KEY (booking_id) REFERENCES bookings(booking_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: You should work with you normalized data. Instead of inserting the whole charter data you should insert just the charter id. If you need the charter name you are able to join it. You avoid data redundance, and it is easier to search and update (what if a charter name has to change, maybe a typo? Then you have to change many JSON objects...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have found the answer... Was kinda silly but maybe this answer will help someone

```
BEGIN;
    DO $$
    DECLARE charter JSON;
    DECLARE bookingId INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        charter := (SELECT row_to_json(t) FROM (SELECT charter_id, name FROM charters) t WHERE charter_id = $1);
        INSERT INTO bookings
            (charter, yacht, email, date, passengers, total, start_hour, end_hour, hotel, arrival_date, charter_price)
        values (charter, '{"test":1}', 'a', '12/10/1995', 8, '78', '123', '123', '123', '123', '132')
            RETURNING booking_id INTO bookingId;
    END $$;
COMMIT;
```